# ActionText blob partial not rendering extra elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, actiontext

I am using ActionText to render some richtext and for some reason I have restrictions in adding extra elements to the rendered partial using the partial provided by actiontext

I require attached images to be wrapped around a table element, so they can be rendered correctly for emails in Outlook.  ActionText seems to always ignore any extra elements in this partial I put in.  Anyone know why this is happening and if any ways to work around this?

This is my partial, where the table elements get ignored:

**/views/active_storage/blobs/_blob.html.erb**

```
<table>
  <Tr>
    <td>
      <figure class="attachment attachment--<%= blob.representable? ? "preview" : "file" %> attachment--<%= blob.filename.extension %> text-center">
        <% if blob.representable? %>
          <%= image_tag rails_representation_url(blob.representation(resize_to_limit: [600, 400])) %>

          <% if caption = blob.try(:caption) %>
            <figcaption class="attachment__caption text-center">
              <%= caption %>
            </figcaption>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </figure>
    </td>
  </Tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue was to do with Action Text using inner method for sanitising strings before render.

I override the allowed attributes and tags in a initialiser:

```
ActionText::ContentHelper.allowed_attributes.add 'style'
ActionText::ContentHelper.allowed_attributes.add 'controls'

ActionText::ContentHelper.allowed_tags.add 'video'
ActionText::ContentHelper.allowed_tags.add 'source'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when I added a custom attribute (data-) to link_to helper in _blob.html.erb, it was not included in the rendered  link tag.

```
<% if blob.representable? %>
  <%= link_to image_tag(blob.representation(resize_to_limit: 
local_assigns[:in_gallery] ? [ 800, 600 ] : [ 1024, 768 ]), 
class: 'rounded'), rails_blob_path(blob), { 'data-fancybox': 'gallery' } %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to know how to get action_name in _blob.html.erb file.
Because I want to show up or off the link to image according to the action name eg, `show`, `edit`.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
# config/initializers/html_sanitation.rb

Rails::Html::WhiteListSanitizer.allowed_tags << 'h2'
```